# About .catch(err) handler

Tags: node.js

I want to know about how to use catch statement.
I used catch handler like following code, and if err occurred in B.find(), I want to know err can be handled in A.catch()
There are two code style, and which is more correct?
I think A.catch include the err of B function and is it right?
If it is right, what do B.catch()?

```
///////  code style 1  /////////////
A.find().then(res => {
    //do something
    B.find().then(res => {
        //do something
    }).catch(err => {
        //catch err handle
        res.send(err)
    })
}).catch(err => {
    //catch err handle
    res.send(err)
})

//////// code style 2  //////////////////
A.find().then(res => {
    //do something
    B.find().then(res => {
        //do something
    })
}).catch(err => {
    //catch err handle
    res.send(err)
})
```

Comment: Code style two is better, but you need to add a return statement for `B.find()` so that the promise is chained correctly to the outer catch handler.

Comment: Could you explain in detail? So you mean err of the B.find() can be accessible in A.catch(). And if I use code style 1, what happened?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, that's why Promises are so powerful. Code style one simply creates a promise in the resolve handler of another promise, this is an anti-pattern and basically makes Promises glorified callbacks. You should be chaining the promises by returning the promises created inside of a `then` or `catch` handler so you can take advantage of the error handling pipeline.

Comment: Could you show me sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always return promises created in handlers of other promises, this will allow you to take full advantage of the `Promise` abstraction. The Promise abstraction is a tool for sequencing asynchronous tasks and improving asynchronous error handling.

You should return `B.find()` so errors can be propagated through the promise chain.

```
A.find().then(res => {
    //do something
    return B.find().then(res => {
        //do something
    })
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error from A.find() or B.find()
    res.send(err)
})
```

You can also structure your promise chain to avoid deeply nested callbacks, usually referred to as the pyramid of doom.

```
A.find().then(res => {
    //do something
    return B.find()
}).then(res => {
    // do something with B.find() result
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error from A.find() or B.find()
    res.send(err)
})
```

If you use `async/await` syntax it may help to see how Promises allow you to think about asynchronous programming in a synchronous way, which is generally much easier for developers to understand.

```
try {
    const a = await A.find();
    const b = await B.find();
} catch (err) {
    // handle error from A.find() or B.find()
    res.send(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer `A` can handle inner `B`'s error only if you return `B` in a [chaining pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)

Otherwise, you'll get `UnhandledPromiseRejection` in `nodejs` (or `uncaught exception` in browsers, verified only on Firefox)

Here's an illustration:
Here `getPromise`'s rejection is handled by `anotherP`'s `catch` since the promise was `returned`

```js
function getPromise() {
  return Promise.reject('reject');
}

function anotherP() {
  return Promise.resolve('resolve');
}

anotherP()
  .then(d => {
    console.log(d)
    return getPromise()
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

(open your browser console to see `uncaught exception`)
Here you don't see the `reject` message because the outer `anotherP`'s `catch` does not catch `getPromise`'s rejection. The two promises can be thought of as running in different future context so the rejection of one is not in scope of the other

```js
function getPromise() {
  return Promise.reject('reject');
}

function anotherP() {
  return Promise.resolve('resolve');
}

anotherP()
  .then(d => {
    console.log(d)
    getPromise()
      .then(v => console.log(v))
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: If there is no return statement, what happened? A.catch can't include the err of B? Then only B.catch can be implemented?

Comment: Yes. A cannot catch B's error. While running the second snippet, open your browser's console

Answer (score 0):

According standard coding practice, You should use Promise chaining. So, you will have one catch block to trace all errors.

```
A.find()
   .then(res => {
         //do something
         return B.find();
    })
    .then(res => {
        //do something
        res.send(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        //catch err handle
        res.send(err)
    });
```

**Refer**
https://javascript.info/promise-chaining